# C Library for Advanced Trigonometry?

Tags: c, static-libraries, trigonometry

I am looking for a library that has things like:

- Find the intersection points between 2 circles
- Find the tangents between a point and a circle
- Find the tangents between 2 circles

Stuff like that. I have done the research and found the answers, but there must be a library for this stuff.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/ ......GNU scientific library

Comment: Don't you think that this operations are so simple that there is no library which can do it directly? Just use `-lm` and a simple scholar geometry.

Comment: There are a ton of libraries that support coordinate geometry, but circle geometry is a reason to use trig and I'd be interested to see a proper answer. Writing these kinds of functions _robustly_ does take some effort.

Comment: These are geometry problems, not trigonometry ("a branch of mathematics that studies triangles and the relationships between the lengths of their sides and the angles between those sides").

Answer (score 1):

**C89** contains a header file called `<math.h>` which contains library functions to compute Trigonometric functions (`sin()`, `cos()`, `tan()`, `asin()`, `acos()`, `atan()` and `atan2()`) and Hyperbolic
functions (`sinh()`, `cosh()`, `tanh()`, `asinh()`, `acosh()` and `atanh()`) which might be of help to you. But as far as I know there are no standard C functions to cater to your needs directly. Either you have to create your own functions with the help of the above mentioned functions or depend on a language like Python, MATLAB or Mathematica in which most of the mathematical functions are already implemented in the standard library.

**C99** also adds functions in the header file `<complex.h>` to perform trigonometric functions on complex numbers (`csin()`, `ccos()`, `ctan()`, etc.) by introducing a new keyword `_Complex`.

The **GNU Scientific Library (GSL)** is a numerical library for C which contains functions to perform various mathematical operations.